# ODBC, C++, Retrieving ntext from first column

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, odbc

I can retrieve ntext columns with SQLGetData such a way.

```
retCode = SQLGetData(input_hstmt, column, SQL_C_BINARY, 
            target_ptr, NULL, &binding_ref.buffer_length);
target_ptr = new BYTE[buffer_length + 1];
retCode = SQLGetData(input_hstmt, column, SQL_C_WCHAR, 
            target_ptr, buffer_length + 1, &strlen_or_ind);
```

The problem is there are other columns, which I would like to bind and to use SQLFetch with them  afterwards. For using SQLGetData, number of column to retrieve from have to be greater than the highest number of bound column ones. What is the most proper way to retrieve the data?
E.g. sort columns and retrieve them in right order, avoid using SQLFetch, anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure there is a "right" solution to this, its just a feature of the SQL Server driver that it reads data out of the TDS input buffer as you can SQLGetData. However you may be able to work around this by setting the cursor type to scrollable. The SQL Server does not return large objects by default when using a cursor and will go back to the database are refetch when you call SQLGetData. Its not ideal, but may help you with the problem.